# Lightning board 3 meters

Tags: physics, lightning

In France, you will see some signs like the one below:

[image]

Those signs are next to buildings which have lightning rods. They also have some conductors to make the current go from the rooftop to the earth like the one below:

[image]

[image]

The panel says that in case of storm, we have to be at least 3 meters away from the conductors.

How does it work? Why is it only 3 meters? Is it something in the earth that allows to consider only 3 meters as a safe distance? It is said that a whole flock of sheep can die due to lightning. I do not think that a flock makes a circle with a radius smaller than 3 meters.

Comment: "it is said": be **very** careful with such statements, they are often wrong. But yes, you (or huddled groups of sheep) can die if you get hit by lightning. The sheep would be fine in a stable with such a protection, though, because the lightning wouldn't hit the sheep, but the rod, and the current would travel through the rod, and not through the sheep.

Comment: They need a row of chairs at  3m radius. What a show :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *It is said that a whole flock of sheep can die due to lightning.*

The sheep are in a field getting wet and, any lightning strike will directly hit the surface of the ground and form a **large area** of ever-decreasing equipotential circles emanating from that strike zone. It is the fact that the front feet of the sheep might be on an equipotential zone that is thousands of volts different to its back feet that causes me to think about getting the mint sauce from the cupboard.

With a lightning rod, the very high conduction of the copper and the fact that it delivers the lightning strike energy to quite deep in the ground means that the different equipotential zones at the surface of the ground are not dangerous at some distance and, if that distance is 3 metres (haven't done the math) then that's good enough for me.

However, the sheep might still be at risk at 3 metres from the lightning rod due to their four-legged nature and the sizable gap between front and back feet (less of a problem for humans with shoes).

Comment: plus, this is about risk reduction in the face of uncontrolled local structures, and not a lab experiment. I bet they did some modelling, and then chose a distance that was easy to communicate ("do not step closer than 2674 mm if you want to live with a probability of higher than 1-1/1000 in the case of a lightning strike to the rod, given our expected moisture model" simply fits way worse on a sign than "in case of severe weather, stay 3m away!"), and good enough that with 99.9% probability they won't have a news craze that causes a French panic about people …

Comment: … being less safe instead of safer due to lightning rods (which in the end would lead to stubborn people disconnecting their lightning rods exactly because "they up there have decided I need that, so it must be bad for my safety), and then actual death.

Comment: Oh and re 3m: also, mechanical dangers. Lightning rods being hit expand very quickly and straighten very quickly, so, it might simply be a good idea to not stand next to the screw that holds the rod in the wall.

Comment: Also note that sheep (horses, cows, deer etc.) with their four legged disposition will have the current flow through their heart, thus stopping it.  If humans assumed the downward  dog yoga position, they too would meet the same fate as the sheep.

Comment: So you mean it will work as the rod is highly conducting and as the end of the rod is deeply pulled down in the earth ? I have to see the end of the rod as a large area of decreasing equipotential spheres emanating from that strike zone rather than of circle ?

Comment: @Jess I can't speak for all ends-of-earth-rods but, the big ones used in electricity supply have a big conductive block at the end that makes contact with a lot of soil/earth and, it's very deep down. Meaning that lines of equipotential run almost parallel with the surface of the earth meaning that electrocution is really not that easy. Yes, regard them as spheres rather than as circles.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and answer really helpful !

Answer (score 1):

At 3 meters distance, the lightning's high energy potential is approximated to not pose a threat anymore. Yes, earth / ground will 'dilute' the energy.

Sheep can't read signs.

Comment: There's a term for this, step potential. Not only lightning can pose a danger, downed power lines too. See https://www.osha.gov/sites/default/files/2018-12/fy11_sh-22312-11_StepPotentialQuickCard.pdf